# Typescript function with an argument that gets its keys from another argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create a function that accepts two arguments, the first is an object that includes an array of strings that are the required fields for the second argument. e.g

```
const configOptions = {
    config1: {
        value: string,
        props: ['firstProp', 'secondProp']
    }
};

myFunc(configOptions.config1, {
  'firstProp': 'first value', // <-- firstProp and secondProp are required because they are defined in config.props
  'secondProp': 'second value',
});
```

I can achieve this by referencing the specific config in the function declaration and doing a const assertion on the config options

```
const configOptions = {
  config1: {
      value: 'a string value',
      props: ['firstProp', 'secondProp']
  }
} as const;

function myFunc<T extends typeof configOptions.config1>(
  option: T,
  params: { [key in typeof option.props[number]]: string }
) {}

myFunc(configOptions.config1, {
  firstProp: 'first value',
  secondProp: 'second value',
});
```

But I want to achieve this more generically so I could call the same function and use one of many configs. Is this possible?

Here is a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ydyt4v

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) with a [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) will allow inferring the type of the `config`. This inferred generic can then be used to define the type for the second argument.

```
const configOptions = {
    config1: {
        value: 'string',
        props: ['firstProp', 'secondProp']
    },
    config2: {
        value: 'string',
        props: ['one', 'two']
    }
} as const;

// Define the base shape (most general shape) of the config. 
// I used the const assertion (`as const`) above so defining the props as 
// readonly made this work nicely but that could be changed.
interface BaseConfig {
    value: string;
    props: readonly string[]
}

const myFunc = <
    // Define a generic `Config` that adheres (extends) the base shape (BaseConfig).
    // It represents the first argument and is inferred from the passed `config`.
    Config extends BaseConfig
>(
    config: Config,
    // Define the input values type based on the passed `Config`.
    // Specifically, we want the values of the props key.
    // And those keys are for a record, with a string value.
    values: Record<Config["props"][number], string>
) => {
    // TODO: implement as needed.
    return null;
}

// Okay.
myFunc(configOptions.config1, {
    'firstProp': 'first value',
    'secondProp': 'second value',
});

// Property 'secondProp' is missing in type.
myFunc(configOptions.config1, {
    'firstProp': 'first value',
});

// Okay.
myFunc(configOptions.config2, {
    'one': '1',
    'two': '2'
});

// Property 'one' is missing in type.
myFunc(configOptions.config2, {
    'two': '2'
});
```

[TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=55&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBKYDMCWBzA8gByk8EYF4YBvAKBnLnGRQEYAuYsi5gNwEMAbAVwFMGByaACckYFPwA0TZuQxCQGCAwDa-ZEOgAFeRkkxBPeABNtC-gF1pMAL5Tm8agCYGpGRXbc++4aPF23MHIKSjCq4Dx6-FAA7iAWVtYk1jBsePDQANwkJAD0OTAAIjzIYDwwUAAWZQBGqWUQFWwYZQAUALYg0DAoPKVCnDANTTwAlDAgCOVVlIioAHQwufkAkjBcEDxGU2XpsKkbQtjgMC0ABqkz0KdjbNUgLPUgMEbFor7bgTp4F0swQjxsIzgDgATxgbUBZUqSDwsSEAGsYGAkMAeKCYNUuLBKmxYKAuBwttUdo0xJs5iRRFAeEIEGxUTAAEJ1ADCVFQjFYnF4DB8YiyzCCigY-0BwLBfJQyksiRIu3BIIAYlwwMACDAADxWPKFV6lFLdXo0lEwU5s2YoU5TXEpIxVf54Fo8AAe1LARggY0qNTqg0azROzI25uoIwpzB1y1g-zkPA2YCgeG9MHUXTYQhQXDavT27pgMPziBp-y2CHkbQ+GH2m1NDlQp3DFBDHJdbo9TNZ7JQJAAfC0rHWUAxmyh-OQdUUSlDpqIMFiYB5eEmQQHahstsdk1WIOvTSOG9r8gBlZrAJDIYCcUESGDRMrRNgJj6LuPjSZbr4weE8EGN8f5ABBPNKk6MpvxBb5-hTEAhANf5QCEIwb2iJBKgNSUF25Hg-0wzwQgAJUMGCjA1EdlAAIiFCByPMZQwCzYkhHMG9JR7EgxnwHtOQoHUABU0AKNAGCQNoMA4HhsyfC5Sk2ckrH+KAuCEMAkQJDgsllHU0HhNhfxINolRVYAWkHTAjkgOZBxoG9XAoNQkA0KBTF0ARU1gF9JCsAxjGc-gBA2YxcN4TzrBGLJfmcmkoDBbzwBMHR+HzPA2hhCB3lEcoV2w-TDNVEyuzMnALKsmyvLc3zXIcroPKkULwq0nS9IM5U8tMrAiogSyu0cUrmH4cI-P0GhPL6mI4gERx+CSMLsh1SLDhigakvBVL0pU6LmgpZqjPyi1CtwLqLR67jyCiWJBv4SbpoyIA)